# How to Insert OppLineitems REST api

Tags: rest

I have created a REST api to insert the Opportunity in other SF org, based on certain condition in the originating SF org. But I also have to insert the opp line items, from this opportunity. As this is my first REST API task, I am not sure how should I proceed. Its working for opportunity insert though. I have to grab this id and Product code to Insert OPP LINE ITEMS.

POST method below

```
global static String createOpportunity() {  
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;  
        RestResponse response = RestContext.response; 
        blob body = request.requestBody; 
        //Get the data from the body  
        String jsonToParse = body.toString();  
        Map<String,Object> myRes = (Map<String,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonToParse);
        String opptyName = (String)myRes.get('Name');
        String dtid = (String)myRes.get('DT_ID__c');
        Account acct = [SELECT Status__c, CIO_in_Process_for_this_Account__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: dtid LIMIT 1];
        if(acct.CIO_in_Process_for_this_Account__c && acct.Status__c != 'Inactive'){
            Opportunity oppty = new Opportunity(Name = opptyName,
                                                AccountId = dtid,
                                                CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD');
            insert oppty;   
            return null;
        }
        else{
            return('Submission Error');
        }
    }
}
```

PUT method below

```
if(objAuthenticationInfo.access_token != null){
                HTTP call2 = new Http();
                HTTPRequest request2 = new HttpRequest();
                HTTPResponse response2 = new HttpResponse();
                request2.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + objAuthenticationInfo.access_token);
                request2.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
                Opportunity oppty =[SELECT Name, CloseDate, ForecastCategoryName, LeadSource, DT_ID__c
                                      FROM Opportunity
                                     WHERE Id =: OpptyID];
                string jsonstr = JSON.Serialize(oppty);
                request2.setBody(jsonstr);
                request2.setMethod('POST'); 
                request2.setEndpoint(endPointURL + '/----');
                response2 = call2.send(request2);
                String responsebody = response2.getbody();
                String responsewithoutQuote = responsebody.remove('"');
                oppty.StageName = responsewithoutQuote;
                update oppty;
```

Comment: What does your payload look like? does it include the line items? If so use that to create them. Your questions does not have enough detail around your issue to provide a specific answer.. All you gave us was working code.

Comment: Dear Eric, thanks for your reply. Pay load is 10-15 Opp line items per Opportunity. My issue is, I am not sure how to insert Opp Line items record in the same transaction, grabbing the opportunity ID, which gets inserted, as per my code above

Comment: After inserting the Opportunity, simply create the line items, assign them the opportunity id and then insert them. You do not have to do them in a single DML call but this may help if you insist that you need to: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_foreign_keys.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir. I appreciate your help. I shall look into it and update you, if its working

Comment: @Eric How should I get the list of all the Opp line items from the other org? If I have 10 opp line items in one org, I have to grab that info right? Thats where I am being lost. I have to capture those 10 line items in my PUT method. How to pass that info to the other org

Comment: You said they were in your payload so use what was sent.

Comment: @Eric -- Bro I gave you the scenario. I am not getting how to actually include it in my PUT method. i.e how to include it in my payload

Comment: I am not your "Bro". You said "Pay load is 10-15 Opp line items" good luck

Comment: @Eric- I beg your pardon for not reading your comment completely about the payload. I did not include the Opp Line items in my payload. and also I apologize for addressing you as "Bro"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you "PUT" method in your question is actually the method from the originating org that is sending the data and not a "PUT" method in a rest resource.

With that said, I am also assuming that the OpportunityLineitems exist in the originating org (You have not put anything in the question about that).

Simply subquery for the opportunitylineitems and they will get serialized along with the Opportunity:

```
Opportunity oppty =[SELECT Name, CloseDate, ForecastCategoryName, LeadSource, DT_ID__c, (Select ID, TotalPrice, ...... From OpportunityLineItems) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: OpptyID];

string jsonstr = JSON.Serialize(oppty);
```

Then in your destination org simply deserialize like so:

```
Opportunity o = (Opportunity)son.deserialize(xxxxxx,Opportunity.class);

OpportunityLineItems[] oppLines = o.OpportunityLineItems;
```

*Bro* ;)

Comment: :: Thanks a ton. by "PUT" I am referring to the Rest resource. The second method in my question. This is actually in the originating org. I guess you answered my question BRO (with your permission) :)

Comment: @user3303348 Did I answer it? Not sure if that was sarcasm or not since the answer is not marked as correct.........

Comment: I dare not be sarcastic bro. I am actually using what you told and trying to code. Coz there are products look up related to opplineitems and cannot just create those opplineitems in other org, as I need to map it based on product code. Completely in a helpless situation bro...

Comment: Use the product code from the Opportunity line item to get the relevant products int he destination org. This all assumes the same codes exist in the destination org. If not, then you will have to have a way to match up the originating and destination orgs. You can then set the value on the OLI in the destination org before inserting. (Set the ID to null on the OLI and the OpportunyID to the inserted oppId). Make a map of org Opp ID to New Opp Id to use

Comment: You are very right @Eric. Product code is same. Did not get your last line "Make a map of org Opp ID to New Opp Id to use".

Comment: When you insert the Opp in the new org, it will have a new ID. You need that ID to put on the LineItem. If you have more that one Opportunity in your payload you need map of old to new ID so you can set it properly on the line items

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48851/discussion-between-user3303348-and-eric).